# Hyperledger-Burrow, is there a way to set miningreward and gasprice to 0?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-burrow

Hello fellow Bugseekers,

I am currently working on a Prototype where I need a private blockchain that is solidity-compatible and I don't want to use ethereum, so Hyperledger Burrow seems like a good idea.

The thing is: The Incentive for Miners, in my prototype, is "beeing part of the system" (with all its benefits). So I don't need the mining-reward. TxFee is actually bad because I would like everyone with an account (no matter how their balance is) to be able to make transactions.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank You in advance for your Time.